# mysql search by title in last 100 records

Tags: php, mysql

My case is, when someone is posting to my news web data with 600k records,
they can create the same title which someone just posted in the last few hours with same subject.

```
data: sid|title|desc|timestamp|userid
```

Usually I use:

```
select sid from ".$prefix."_stories WHERE title = '".$subject."' limit 0,1
```

It searches all data for `$subject` then notice poster if have they have the same title.
I need a query which searches in the last 100 records.

I tried the following, but this did not work:

```
select sid from ".$prefix."_stories WHERE title = '".$subject."' and sid > MAX(sid)-100 limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a primary key, incrementing by 1 with every record (which will put newest at the bottom), just do this:

```
SELECT sid, title
FROM ".$prefix."_stories
ORDER BY sid DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

This will select the last 100 records

Good point by Michael in my comments... Edit to code and further comment:

Removing the where clause, this will select the last 100 records... Run a loop to check to see if the title or summary already exists:

```
while ($row = $result) {
   if $subject = $row['title'] {
      $duplicate = TRUE;
      endwhile;
   }
}
```

Just compare the resulting data.  Thanks Michael

Comment: This will return up to 100 matching titles, not search the most recently added 100 records for `$subject`.

Comment: As I know.. this still collect all sid wich have same title in all records then show the last 100 records..  IN-fact i need it search only on last 100 records only.. thanks anyway!

Comment: @BinhNguyen No, without the `WHERE`, and assuming that `sid` is your primary key, this will collect the last 100 records entered into the database.  If `sid` is not your primary key, then in the `SELECT` also enter your primary key in front of `sid, title`, change the `ORDER BY` from `sid` to the primary key and it will collect the last (newest) 100 records in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a subquery that returns the last 100 `sid`. Note, I have omitted the PHP concatenations for brevity here.

```
SELECT
  last100.sid
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      sid,
      title
    FROM $prefix._stories 
    ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 100
  ) last100
WHERE
  last100.title = '$subject'
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested this query but it not work, no result found :)

Comment: thanks! i did test with this query before but the result not acurated .. for eg: data has 120 records: the record sid = 50 with title "aaa" then record sid = 120 with same title="aaa" now i test to search with your query it only show the record with id=50 so the last record with id=120 do not found .. ! so bad .. any ideal ?

Comment: sorry i did not corect some typo in query.. actualy it work very good

Comment: @BinhNguyen I thought it would. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by sid (descending, so newest entries come first) and limit results to 100:

```
$sql = "select t.sid from (select sid, title from ".$prefix."_stories ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 0,100) t WHERE title = '".$subject."';"
```

Be sure to chek $subject to avoid SQL Injection (better: Use prepared statements / PDO).

Comment: This is the same as I originally had my answer.  As Michael noted in my comments, this will collect up to 100 records containing the `title` with `$subject` rather than search the last 100 records.